# Set, List and Map equality comparison with Lambda check

Tags: java, collections

I'd like to be able to compare two objects with different equality checks. This should work if they're in a `Set`, `List` or `Map` as well.

An example use case is testing of deserialzation of a entity which might contain sensitive information, like passwords, the server side, but not in a REST response.

I'd be interested if you see any design flaws or uncovered issues.

I'd also be grateful for a hint about existing implementations of FLOSS projects.

```
/**
 * Used by
 * {@link Tools#equals(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, EqualsCheck) }.
 *
 * @author richter
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface EqualsCheck<T> {

    boolean equals(T a, T b);
}
```

and the methods:

```
/**
 * Does what
 * {@link java.util.Objects#equals(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object) }
 * does, except allows to use methods to check equality as lambda.
 *
 * @param <T> allows to restrict the type of arguments to compare
 * @param a the first item
 * @param b the first item
 * @param equalsCheck the equality check to use
 * @return {@code true} if {@code a} and {@code b} are equal to each other,
 * {@code false} otherwise
 */
public static <T> boolean equals(T a, T b,
        EqualsCheck<T> equalsCheck) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && equalsCheck.equals(a, b));
}

/**
 * Checks that all elements in {@code a} are contained in {@code b} and vice versa.
 *
 * @param <T> allows to restrict the type of arguments to compare
 * @param a the first set
 * @param b the second set
 * @param equalsCheck the equality check to use
 * @return {@code true} if all elements in {@code a} are contained in
 * {@code b} and {@code b} contains no other items, {@code false} otherwise
 */
public static <T> boolean equalsSet(Set<T> a, Set<T> b,
        EqualsCheck<T> equalsCheck) {
    if(a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    if(a.stream().anyMatch(a0 -> b.stream().noneMatch(b0 -> equalsCheck.equals(a0, b0)))) {
        return false;
    }
    if(b.stream().anyMatch(b0 -> a.stream().noneMatch(a0 -> equalsCheck.equals(b0, a0)))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Checks that all elements in {@code a} are contained in {@code b} at the
 * same position and vice versa.
 *
 * @param <T> allows to restrict the type of arguments to compare
 * @param a the first list
 * @param b the second list
 * @param equalsCheck the equality check to use
 * @return {@code true} if all elements in {@code a} are contained in
 * {@code b} at the same position and {@code b} contains no other elements,
 * {@code false} otherwise
 */
public static <T> boolean equalsList(List<T> a, List<T> b,
        EqualsCheck<T> equalsCheck) {
    if(a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    if(a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    Iterator<T> aItr = a.iterator();
    Iterator<T> bItr = b.iterator();
    while(aItr.hasNext()) {
        T aNxt = aItr.next();
        T bNxt = bItr.next();
        if(!equalsCheck.equals(aNxt, bNxt)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Checks that all mappings between key and value in {@code a} are contained
 * in {@code b} and vice versa.
 *
 * @param <K> allows to restrict the type of keys in both maps
 * @param <V> allows to restrict the type of values in both maps
 * @param a the first map
 * @param b the second map
 * @param equalsCheckKey the equality check to use for keys
 * @param equalsCheckValue the equality check to use for values
 * @return {@code true} if the key set of {@code a} and {@code b} is equals
 * as defined by
 * {@link #equalsSet(java.util.Set, java.util.Set, EqualsCheck) }
 * and all keys in {@code a} are mapped to the same values as they are in
 * {@code b}, {@code false} otherwise
 */
public static <K,V> boolean equalsMap(Map<K,V> a, Map<K,V> b,
        EqualsCheck<K> equalsCheckKey,
        EqualsCheck<V> equalsCheckValue) {
    if(a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    if(a.size() != b.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    if(!equalsSet(a.keySet(), b.keySet(), equalsCheckKey)) {
        return false;
    }
    for(K key : a.keySet()) {
        if(!equalsCheckValue.equals(a.get(key), b.get(key))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The code is now available at https://gitlab.com/krichter/equals-lambda and https://github.com/krichter722/equals-lambda or as Maven artifact `de.richtercloud:equals-lambda:1.1` from Sonatype releases.

Comment: Are you sure _equalsSet_ works as intended?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong here, but it seems you check not only _Checks that all elements in {@code a} are contained in {@code b}_ but also Checks that all elements in {@code b} are contained in {@code a}

Comment: @dfhwze Correct. If only the first would be checked I'd check whether a is a equals or a subset of b. I want to check for equality. The Javadoc comment is thus wrong. I'll correct that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### equals

You have provided this method, but don't reuse it in the other methods. For instance, when you do:

> ```
>  if(!equalsCheck.equals(aNxt, bNxt)) {
>         return false;
>  }
> ```

you could have done the below to take into account the null checks:

```
   if(!equals(aNxt, bNxt, equalsCheck)) {
        return false;
   }
```

### equalsSet

This could improved, by:

- make buffer for set b
- loop set a, remove any b from buffer that is found that equals; exit when no match
- if any remaining items in buffer, the sets are not equal

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no need to use an `Iterator` for you list compare since you can simply compare the objects inside of the list directly

```
boolean hasMismatch = IntStream.range(0,a.size()).allMatch(e -> a.get(e).equals(a.get(e)));
```

or using your functionallity again

```
boolean hasMismatch = IntStream.range(0,a.size()).allMatch(e -> equalsCheck.equals(a.get(e), b.get(e));
```

### NOTE

`richtercloud.project1.jar.controller` is an interesting package name - maybe you can find something more suitable

Comment: Mhmm... accessing a `List` with `get(int)` can cause `O(length^2)` for linked list or similar implementation whereas an `Iterator` cost `O(1)`, maybe `O(length)` for construction and `O(length)` for the iteration resulting in `O(length)` vs. `O(length^2)`. The package name is not part of code review.